# Extending continuous function on arbitrary set (only requiring continuity on original set)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and suppose that $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

It is well-known (Kirzbrauns theorem) that if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, then there exists $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \tilde{f}(x)$ for all $x \in A$ and such that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous. Similarly, if $A$ is closed, then Tietze's extension theorem gives the existence of such a $\tilde{f}$.

I would like to know whether just continuity of $f$ suffices for the existence of $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \tilde{f}(x)$ for all $x \in A$ and such that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous at all $x \in A$ (that is, I do not care whether $\tilde{f}$ is continuous outside of $A)$.

Is this possible or is there a counter-example?

Comment: No, it's obviously false. Simply look at $x\mapsto 1/x$

Comment: @Andrew This function is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$? I do not see how this is a counter-example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paper answers the question in the affirmative (Theorem 3.1): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864198001655